# How to make jar file with sbt with external java jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, jar, sbt

I need to make jar file with set with external java jar file.

I made jar file by the following, while putting the external jar file in the `myProject/lib` folder, which is successful:

```
sbt compile
sbt package
```

However, executing the jar file created by this way as follows

```
scala myProject.jar
```

failed with the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` exception.

Whereas the project is executing well in Eclipse Scala IDE.

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem was that sbt was not cleaned; that is, it was solved after executing `sbt clean`.

We have confirmed that after `sbt clean`, both of `sbt compile ; sbt package` and `sbt assembly` worked.

Also, we confirmed that it worked with or without adding `unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += {baseDirectory.value / "lib"}` in `build.sbt`.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may have problem missing dependencies as `scala package` does only packs your artifact alone. This way, when running the jar, you need to add dependencies into classpath.
If you wish to build a standlone runnable jar, use `sbt assembly` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code in `sbt` does it work?

In your build.sbt you need to have a line like this to load the external jar(s) from a custom folder at build time.

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += {baseDirectory.value / "lib"}
```

The above line loads from the `current_folder/lib` all the jars when you run
`sbt assembly` or `package`.